# How to install Xdebug with PhpStorm on localhost on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

How to install Xdebug with PhpStorm on localhost on Ubuntu?
I'm using PHP 7.2 and PhpStorm 2018.2.

I tried `install apt-get install xdebug`, then I've edited `php.ini`

```
[Xdebug]  
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so  
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1  
xdebug.remote_enable = 1  
xdebug.remote_enable = 1  
xdebug.remote_port = 9001  
xdebug.profiler_enable = On  
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp  
xdebug.remote_host=localhost  
xdebug.remote_mode=req  
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

When then when I go to php.info, I see the "IDE Key" a number not PhpStorm, and when I try to put breaking points it ignore them.

Comment: Have you tried following this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html

Comment: @SalvatoreQZeroastro Yes I got nothing

Comment: Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSSjeelN5NU. It's for MacOS but most of the information is generic (except the part about brew; just use apt there).

Answer (score 0):

I fought this a lot, too. Let's see if this helps you. I use windows, but the principle should be the same.

1) Be sure, PHP storm uses the php.ini you edited. It can be different.

[image]

My php.ini xdebug settings:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="E:\Apache24\php\7.2.9\php_xdebug-2.7.0beta1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="E:\Apache24\php\7.2.9\tmp"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

2) If you see this, then the extension is not installed correctly:

[image]

3) Check, if xdebug extension's version corresponds to your php version.

4) Press "Debug" button, not "Run"

5) Works well with breakpoints:

[image]